# BigQuery REPEATED field contains

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to check if a BigQuery REPEATED field contains a specific value?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column1 CONTAINS ("Test Value") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM testdata
```

when column1 is a field of type STRING of mode REPEATED. 
I have multiple REPEATED columns of the same nature so having to flatten them all out seems tedious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT 
  id_or_whatever_key_column_you_have, 
  SUM(CASE 
        WHEN column1 CONTAINS ("Test Value") THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END
     ) WITHIN RECORD AS matches
FROM testdata
```

I realised - while copy/paste from your example I left some extra that can be removed without losing result - so it not only tells you if you have matches or not (true/false) but rather gives you count of matches within each record:

```
SELECT 
  id_or_whatever_key_column_you_have, 
  SUM(column1 CONTAINS ("Test Value")) WITHIN RECORD AS matches
FROM testdata
```

I think Danny's answer has triggered this in my mind :o)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`SOME`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#some) to accomplish this, e.g.

```
SELECT SOME(column1 CONTAINS ("Test Value")) WITHIN RECORD FROM testdata
```