# standard sql query to get matching record field with another table (Google BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables

1) table `main`

```
   id    phone.type  phone.id
==============================
|   1   | android | adkfjagp |
|       | android | asdfasdf |
|       | iphone  | akfj2341 |
|       | iphone  | ada93519 |
------------------------------
```

and I have another table which stores a bunch of android phone ids like this

2) table `android`

```
==============
|  adkfjagp  |
|   ...      |
--------------
```

Is there a way I can get all rows in table main where the row contains a record with type android and id that is in also table android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below should make it

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT m.*
FROM main AS m
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id) AS ids  FROM android) AS a
WHERE  (
  SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM UNNEST(phone) AS phone 
  WHERE phone.type = 'android' 
  AND phone.id IN UNNEST(a.ids)
) > 0
```

you can test it with below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH main AS (
  SELECT 
    1 AS id, 
    [STRUCT<type STRING, id STRING>
      ('android', 'adkfjagp'),
      ('android', 'asdfasdf'),
      ('iphone', 'akfj2341'),
      ('iphone', 'ada93519')
     ] AS phone UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    2 AS id, 
    [STRUCT<type STRING, id STRING>
      ('android', 'adkfjagp1'),
      ('android', 'bbbbbbbb1'),
      ('android', 'akfj2341'),
      ('iphone', 'ada93519')
     ] AS phone
),
android AS (
  SELECT 'adkfjagp' AS id UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbbbbbbb' 
)
SELECT m.*
FROM main AS m
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(id) AS ids  FROM android) AS a
WHERE  (
  SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM UNNEST(phone) AS phone 
  WHERE phone.type = 'android' 
  AND phone.id IN UNNEST(a.ids)
) > 0
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN." Do you know how I can solve this? Thank you!

Comment: i see  - makes sense  - let me rewrite it :o)

Comment: @Isa - try this now

Comment: @Isa - how it looks now on your side?

Comment: Thank! This looks nice. but when I run it on a large dataset with around 1 TB of data, bigquery seems to be complaining about "resources exceeded during query execution."

Comment: @Isa - up to you - but would be great if you can consider this as next question. i think your current question is answered so you can at least vote on it - if you think you cannot also accept it. but as I said - i think - at least formally - your question is answered

Comment: Of course. I think this is great for this question. Thank you:)