# How can I count the total no of rows which is not containing some value in array field? It should include null values as well

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, count, unnest

```
| names                              | 
| -----------------------------------| 
| null                               | 
| null                               |
| [{name:'test'},{name:'test1'}]     | 
| [{name:'test'},{name:'test1'}]     |
| [{name:'test1'},{name:'test2'}]    |
```

I want to count the no of rows which does not have the value 'test' in the name key.

Here it should give answer as 3 (Row no 1, 2 and 5th row) because all these row do not contain the value 'test'.

Answer (score 1):

Use below approach

```
select count(*)
from your_table
where 0 = ifnull(array_length(regexp_extract_all(names, r"\b(name:'test')")), 0)
```

you can test it with below data (that resemble whatever you presented in your question)

```
with your_table as (
  select null names union all
  select null union all
  select "[{name:'test'},{name:'test1'}]" union all
  select "[{name:'test'},{name:'test1'}]" union all
  select "[{name:'test1'},{name:'test2'}]" 
)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: regexp_extract_all accepting string as a first parameter. I am not able to pass the my_table.names in the first parameter. What does represent the first parameter over here?

Comment: as per your sample - `names` is the column name!

Comment: It giving me all rows count. Total fo the table.

Comment: that cannot be true if you correctly use above presented query. use CTE I just provided to do test first and then make sure you properly use it with your real data!

Comment: also, obviously, make sure that sample data you shown in your question is correctly represents your real data as this can potentially be a reason for returning count of all rows in a table :o)

Comment: I think it is because of you take the column type as a string and mine is an array. I am trying with following data set.

```with your_table as (
  select null names union all
  select null union all
  select [('name','test'),('name','test1')] union all
  select [('name','test'),('name','test1')] union all
  select [('name','test1'),('name','test2')] 
)```

Comment: oh, I see. will revisit when have time :o)

Comment: Anyway I found solution by modifying one of your past answer. Thanks a lot for the help! 
Here is your answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42990125/8440056

Comment: great, thank you for confirming :o)

Answer (score 0):

Below approach will work,

```
with your_table as (
     select null names union all   
     select null union all   
     select [('name','test'),('name','test1')] union all   
     select [('name','test'),('name','test1')] union all   
     select [('name','test1'),('name','test2')]  
)


SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM your_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM UNNEST(your_table.names) AS names
  WHERE names IN (('name','test'))
)
```