# How do i filter rows in bigquery, where a nested repeated field contains certain value?

Tags: google-bigquery

Lets assume the nested repeated field is Experience.Company, Experience.Months.
Now if the Experience record contains , say, "GE" in Experience.Company, i want to skip the entire record.

The query i tried is something of this sort:

```
select name, location from table_name where Experience.Company != "GE".
```

This obviously doesn't work, since i get the record for other values.

I tried OMIT IF, with the same result.

Anything else I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refered to

[BigQuery REPEATED field contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277110/bigquery-repeated-field-contains?rq=1)

so the query looks like:

```
Select column1, column2, 
sum(experience.company contains "GE") within record as matches 
from [mytable] 
having matches = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `table_name` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'John' AS Name, 'LA' AS Location, [STRUCT<Company STRING, Months INT64>('Google', 24), ('Apple', 36)] AS Experience UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Nick', 'SF', [STRUCT<Company STRING, Months INT64>('GE', 12), ('Microsoft', 48)] AS Experience UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Mike', 'LV', [STRUCT<Company STRING, Months INT64>('Facebook', 24), ('Cloudera', 36)] AS Experience 
)
SELECT name, location FROM `table_name`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(Experience) WHERE Company = 'GE')
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail.I need to use legacy SQL. I finally ended up using the solution explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277110/bigquery-repeated-field-contains?rq=1

Comment: make sense. consider voting that answer then :o)